# How to let the django thumbnail show me image?

Tags: django

Currenlty,I have learn django from the http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/photo.html and I meet a problem!I want show the thumbnail image on the 'Thumbnail item' but it's just show the html code:

```
<a href="/photos/1414.jpg><img border="0" alt="" src="/photos/1414.jpg" height="40"/></a>
```

I have define the class Image method like below:

```
def thumbnail(self):
    return """<a href="/%s><img border="0" alt="" src="/%s" height="40"/> """ % ((self.image.name,self.image.name))
```

The attribute of Class Image have define like that:

```
class Image(Models.Model):
    #The rest of another code
    image=models.ManyToManyField(upload_to="photos/")
    #....another code ..
```

I have check my path have create a photos on my project 'myweb/photos/'
How can i let the page understand it's html code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have no idea why you're using a `ManyToMany` field for this use case. You need to be using an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#imagefield).

The field you define as an `ImageField` will have a `url` property, which is what you use to reference the relative path to the file.

Second, don't mix HTML and Python in your model class. Django has templating specifically for this use case:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def thumbnail(self):
        return render_to_string('thumbnail.html', {'image': self})


# thumbnail.html
<img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}" ... />
```

Keep in mind that artificially scaling a full-size image to 40x40 pixels to generate a thumbnail is horribly inefficient, and if there are lots of these, will absolutely crush performance.

As others have mentioned, you can use excellent libraries like [django-easy-thumbnails](https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/) or [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to generate proper, scaled down, optimized versions of these images at whatever dimensions you need.

Comment: Oh,ManyToMany is no actually what i want input ,I just have some mistake to put it here!I have try your method ,and then it's just effective against 'alt ' show me something look like the date-time (default value maybe)! But I try write simple sample !and I no use templates,anyway I can't upload image to stack overflow,so please see my Facebook/photohttps://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=122158394809921&set=a.122155181476909.1073741827.100010472830526&type=3&theater

Comment: Then there's some else wrong with your code that you haven't posted. The `url` property on the `ImageField` has been there since Django was created.

Comment: yeah! I have no set my MEDIA_URL so the cannot load the image at template,and I print self.image.url before render_to_string..I find image there impossible there ! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

please follow the tutorial on [djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/) ..the code on your link is not a right way use django,close it and read official docs

Answer (score 0):

Use the `url` attribute instead of the `name` attribute on the image:

```
def thumbnail(self):
    return """<a href="/%s><img border="0" alt="" src="/%s" height="40"/> """ % ((self.image.url,self.image.url))
```

There is also the excellent tool [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail). It helps with dynamically generating thumbnails in your templates. Install it with `pip install sorl-thumbnail`. You can use it like this:

**template.html**

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail item.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: I replace 'name' to 'url' but still no work! so I try your method 2,But I don't know how to call your template.html,Should I do it by render_to_response('template.html',{}) but it show me error said(template thumbnail no found ). Thank you in advance!